# Copy to all folders batch file?

Tags: batch-file, copy

i want to copy a file (example: a.jpg) to all folders in a directory.

i need something like

```
copy a.jpg */a.jpg
```

do you have a batch file that does something like that?

(ps. i use windows)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the for command

```
for /f "tokens=*" %f in ('dir . /ad/b') do copy "a.jpg" "%f"
```

Remember to use %%f instead of % when placing in a batch file

Comment: What about a hidden or system file?? I tried but it says file not found

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using the `for` command with the `/r` switch, which is used to enumerate a directory tree. For example, this will copy the C:\a.jpg file to the C:\Test folder and all of its subfolders:

```
for /r "C:\Test" %%f in (.) do (
  copy "C:\a.jpg" "%%~ff" > nul
)
```

The `for /r "C:\Test" %%f in (.)` statement enumerates the C:\Test folder and all its subfolders and `%%~ff` returns the current folder name.

Answer (score 2):

you can copy a file in all folders of a directory by using following command

for /F %g in ('dir /AD/B/S') DO copy c:\myfile %g

explanation:

In above command:- 
%g is a variable, 
dir /AD/B/S :- is a command to view all folders and sub folders of a directory,
/F :- is a switch which we used with for command,if we want to iterate through the results of a command enclosed in bracket (in our case it is ('dir /AD/B/S'),
c:\myfile:- is the file which we want to copy in all sub folders