# Copy a file into every folder and its subfolders

Tags: file, batch-file, copy, directory, subdirectory

```
"Here I am"-folder
  |
  |--- mainfolder 1
  |          |
  |          |--- subfolder 1
  |          |--- subfolder 2
  |
  |--- mainfolder 2
  |          |
  |          |--- subfolder 1
  |          |--- subfolder 2
```

I want to place a batch-file into the "Here I am"-folder and execute it from there. It should copy a file named *text.txt* into all mainfolders and into their subfolders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use following script:

```
@echo off
    for /r "%CD%" %%f in (.) do (
      copy "Text.txt" "%%~ff" > nul
    )
```

Credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1321539/1756941

**Edit:**

```
@echo off
    Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    cls
    set currentDirectory=%CD%
    FOR /D %%g IN ("*") DO (
        Pushd %CD%\%%g
        FOR /D %%f IN ("*") DO (
            copy "%currentDirectory%\Text.txt" "%%~ff"
        )
    Popd
    )
pause
```

Comment: Thanks. One last question. How does the code looks like, if the file will be copied only into the subolders but not into the mainfolders?

Comment: See edit for a copy-to-sub-subfolder-only script

Answer (score -2):

Use xcopy command (for windows):

http://www.computerhope.com/xcopyhlp.htm

xcopy c:\temp\1 c:\temp\2 /E